# jQuery DataTables fnGetPosition is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, datatable

Here's what my code does (except the variable is in a more complex system with arrays):

```
var dataTable = $([some-DOM-table]).dataTable().columnFilter();
dataTable.fnGetPosition([some-DOM-tr-object]);
```

I get error 'fnGetPosition is not a function'.

I have included 'jquery.dataTables.min.js' and 'jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js'. I'm a still missing a file or what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3):

I think you missed “.dataTable()” in $([some-DOM-table]);

Below code will help you.
It is working as required.

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js" language="javascript" type="text/javascript">  </script>
<script src="jquery.dataTables.min.js" language="javascript">
</script>
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example tbody tr').click(function () {
            var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
            alert(aPos);
        });
        var oTable = $('#example').dataTable().columnFilter();
    });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<table id="example">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Header</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>data1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data2</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There maybe some correct hint in this answer. The problem is a little bit different since my datatables are supposed to be stored in variables arrays already. I won't be able to continue with this before Monday. Thank you.

Comment: Now I actually store the result of the .dataTable().columnFilter() function in memory (I've corrected the question to match it.) But I still get the same error.

Comment: I have to change oTable object with columnFilter() and able to working fine.
Please get jquery.dataTables.js and jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js from below link I think it will solve your problem.


[https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/source/browse/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js?r=63]
[https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-column-filter/source/browse/trunk/media/js/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js?r=63&spec=svn63]

Comment: I tried both of your file, problem not solved yet. But I have done some more testing closer to the code where the dataTable object is created and it turns out that the TR must be DOM object, no jQuery object. But I still get that function doesn't exist message in the place where I want to use it in my code.

Comment: I found the problem: somewhere in my code I had some part which created some equivalent of $($(myDataTable)). (+ the TR must be a DOM and not jQuery object)

Comment: Ohh ok . Finally you got the solution